# Unexplained 'std::out_of_range' of vector

Tags: c++

I am having an unexplained vector out of range error!

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < studentsVector.size(); i++) {

    bool anyFailedFacultyCourse = false;
    bool anyFailedElectiveCourse = false;
    // Check if all faculty courses are done
    std::cout << currentSemester << std::endl;
    if (currentSemester > 1) {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < currentSemester - 1; j++) {
            if (studentsVector.at(i)->getPlan().at(j).size() > 0) {

                anyFailedFacultyCourse = true;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
```

After debugging, I noticed that the program does get into the first for loop, assigns proper values for `AnyFailedFacultyCourse` and `anyFailedElectiveCourse`, prints the int `currentSemester`. And there it stops!
I put a debug breakpoint at:

```
if (currentSemester > 1)
```

and it just gives me an `out_of_range error` before it even checks! Meaning it does not even get into `if (currentSemester > 1)` 
But there is nothing in between! I mean, how could it throw anything like that when, where it throws the error, I did NOTHING to any vector!

I know this is kind of mysterious, ask for any further information you need.

Further info:
How students vector is declared:

```
std::vector<Student*> studentsVector;
currentSemester:

int currentSemester = 1;
```

Comment: Please show how all the variables you're using are declared. PS: Are you compiling in debug mode? Because if (currentSemester > 1) cannot throw (assuming currentSemester is an int). But when you're compiling with optimizations, the compiler can't really tell which line corresponds to what.

Comment: What is `currentSemester`? How is it declared? Also, what does `getPlan` return? What's the size of that container? Are you sure it's less than `currentSemester`?

Comment: I intentionally did the currentSemester loop for currentSemester-1; because if its first semester I dont want it getting into that loop.
currentSemester is declared as an int before the for of students.
getPlan returns a vector of vectors that hold pointers to courses, irrelavant I must say, I checked it and it works right.

Comment: Self-contained testcase please.

Comment: I recommend you build without any optimization, and with debug info. Then you use the debugger to go through this function line by line, checking that everything looks okay. And that may mean you have to split up the compound access in the `if` statement in the inner `for` loop (i.e. put all in temporary variables, just to make sure they are okay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the breakpoint you set isn't triggered because the condition isn't `true`: that is with `currentSemester` being `1` the condition is clearly `false` and the code skips to whatever is happening after the conditional block. You haven't shown what is happening, there, however.

Comment: Correct.
The breakpoint was not triggered at all. Because currentsemester is 1
The problem is further down in the other loops.
I will check it.
Please excuse my stupidity. Still learning c++ and all the debugging processes.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int j = 0; j < currentSemester - 1; j++) {
>        if (studentsVector.at(i)->getPlan().at(j).size() > 0) {
> ```

Here you do not check that `studentsVector.at(i)->getPlan()` has `j` elements. Your code just assumes it based on what `currentSemester` is, but you never check. And clearly this correlation has broken down somewhere.

Comment: 1) It does have, I declared it hardcoded to have numbers of elements that are even bigger than current semester.
2) Check out the upper answer, it was correct. The debug breakpoint wasnt even triggered there, the problem was in further code.

Comment: It's still a weak point in the code. It would take a small change in distant code to break this and cause exactly the problem you saw. You should make this more defensive.